# How to unnest data with Spark in a generic way?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have some data that is nested, and some of the nested fields can be array. For example:

```
{
  root: {
    x: {
       y: { z: 'foo',....}
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
 root: {
   x: {
      y: [
        { z: 'foo',....}
      ]
   }
 }
}
```

or

```
{
 root: [ {
   x: {
      y: { z: 'foo',....}
   }
 } ]
}
```

In these cases I am trying to group by the `z` field, with something like `df.groupBy('x.y.z')` which works for the first case but fails in the following 2 as there is an array involved. I know that I can `explode` the arrays but how can I do that at runtime if needed and at the exact point? I mean, in the first case there is no need to explode, so it won't do it. In the 2 and 3 case it is needed but at different fields. Is there a way to manage this situation with Pyspark?

Comment: The raw DF should be filtered into 4. 2nd and 3rd are `exploded` as needed and `union`ed with the 1st before `df.groupBy('x.y.z')`. The 4th would be unknown type.

Comment: Can you create a simple code snippet showing the issue and mention the Spark version used?